# How to create large file (require long compress time) on Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I make parallel job now So I'm trying to create  dummyFile and compreaa that on the backgrounds.
Like this

Create dummy file

```
for in ()
 do 
       Compress that file &
done
wait
```

I need to create dummy data So I tried

```
fallocate -l 1g test.txt
```

And

```
tar cfv test.txt
```

But this compress job is done just 5seconds

How can I create dummydata big and required long compress time (3minute~5minute)

Comment: Write a script that puts random data into the file. That will be hard to compress.

Comment: Dump some large number of bytes from /dev/random into a file. You can use something like `dd` to control the size precisely.

Comment: This question is incredibly sloppy. Please clean it up if you want a decent answer.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that tar is not a compression program. gzip is.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww. This could arguably be a scripting issue.

Comment: @jww. Fair enough.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood yours advices and I'm really thankyou. I forced programming on Linux since 3days ago even if I  I have not developed it on Linux. I'll study more and catch the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on here. The first is that `tar` won't compress anything unless you pass it a `z` flag along with what you already have to trigger `gzip` compression:

```
tar cvfz test.txt
```

For a very similar effect, you can invoke `gzip` directly:

```
gzip test.txt
```

The second issue is that with most compression schemes, a gigantic string of zeros, which is likely what you generate, is very easy to compress. You can fix that by supplying random data. On a Unix-like system you can use the pseudo-file `/dev/urandom`. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33634/79307) gives three options in decreasing order of preference, depending on what works:

1. `head` that understands suffixes like `G` for Gibibyte:

   ```
   head -c 1G < /dev/urandom > test.txt
   ```
2. `head` that needs it spelled out:

   ```
   head -c 1073741824 < /dev/urandom > test.txt
   ```
3. No `head` at all, so use `dd`, where file size is block size (`bs`) times `count` (1073741824 = 1024 * 1048576):

   ```
   dd bs=1024 count=1048576 < /dev/urandom > test.txt
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'm understand concepts:)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work. There are some `bash` specific operators.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                  

function createCompressDelete()
{
    _rdmfile="$1"
    cat /dev/urandom > "$_rdmfile" &  # This writes to file in the background
    pidcat=$! #Save the backgrounded pid for later use
    echo "createCompressDelete::$_rdmfile::pid[$pidcat]"
    sleep 2
    while [ -f "$_rdmfile" ]
    do
        fsize=$(du "$_rdmfile" | awk '{print $1}')                                                                                                 
        if (( $fsize < (1024*1024) )); then  # Check the size for 1G
            sleep 10
            echo -n "...$fsize"
        else
            kill "$pidcat"  # Kill the pid
            tar czvf "${_rdmfile}".tar.gz "$_rdmfile"  # compress
            rm -f "${_rdmfile}"  # delete the create file
            rm -f "${_rdmfile}".tar.gz  # delete the tarball
        fi
    done
}

# Run for any number of files
for i in file1 file2 file3 file4
do
    createCompressDelete "$i" &> "$i".log & # run it in the background
done
```